# Speed up For loop with .push_back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, openmp

I'm wondering if we can speed up this loop using OpenMP or CUDA. Currently, it runs fine with sequential processing but I"m trying to optimize my coding:

```
for (int curCol = 0; curCol < numRows; ++curCol){     //Long Loop
        int lb = csc_colIndices[curCol];
        int ub = csc_colIndices[curCol + 1];

        // push back the diagonal value to L matrix
        vec_L_val[curCol].push_back(1.0f);
        vec_L_indices[curCol].push_back(curCol);

        for (int curIndex = lb; curIndex < ub; ++curIndex){
            int curRow = csc_indices[curIndex];
            float curVal = csc_val[curIndex];

            if (!Equal(curVal, 0) && curRow <= curCol){// U entry
                vec_U_val[curCol].push_back(curVal);
                vec_U_indices[curCol].push_back(curRow);
            }
            else if (!Equal(curVal, 0) && curRow > curCol){// L entry
                vec_L_val[curCol].push_back(curVal);
                vec_L_indices[curCol].push_back(curRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

In an effort to parallelise the processing I've tried the following with no effect:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(curCol) shared(curIndex)
```

My suspicion is the use of .push_back but I can be wrong...

How can I improve this code?

Comment: Are you giving your vector an initial size?

Comment: are you referring to vec_L_val and the like? if so, yes.

Comment: Filling `std::vector`s is not a suitable application for parallelism, because multiple threads will be competing for the resource at the same time. I'd leave the filling as a sequential operation, and rather concentrate on leveraging parallelism when you later non-modify process these vectors.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. The main thing is that this is once of the remaining portions of my program that has a bottle neck which is the reason I'm working on it.

Comment: `shared(curIndex)` has to be wrong! (But you're actually OK because you then declare it appropriately as a local inside the, now parallel,, code)

Answer (score 0):

first prealloc the whole thing:

```
for (int curCol = 0; curCol < numRows; ++curCol)
{
    vec_L_val[curCol].resize( SIZE_OF_THE_INNER_VECTOR );
    vec_L_indices[curCol].resize( SIZE_OF_THE_INNER_VECTOR );
    vec_U_val[curCol].resize(SIZE_OF_THE_INNER_VECTOR )
    vec_U_indices[curCol].resize(SIZE_OF_INNER_VECTOR )
}
```

Then your inner loops would probably work faster, as there would not be a need for reallocs inside of the internal vector structures.

```
for (int curCol = 0; curCol < numRows; ++curCol){     //Long Loop
    int lb = csc_colIndices[curCol];
    int ub = csc_colIndices[curCol + 1];

    // push back the diagonal value to L matrix
    vec_L_val[curCol].push_back(1.0f);
    vec_L_indices[curCol].push_back(curCol);

    for (int curIndex = lb; curIndex < ub; ++curIndex){
        int curRow = csc_indices[curIndex];
        float curVal = csc_val[curIndex];

        if (!Equal(curVal, 0) && curRow <= curCol){// U entry
            vec_U_val[curCol].push_back(curVal);
            vec_U_indices[curCol].push_back(curRow);
        }
        else if (!Equal(curVal, 0) && curRow > curCol){// L entry
            vec_L_val[curCol].push_back(curVal);
            vec_L_indices[curCol].push_back(curRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I'll give it a try, Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Tomaz, I've tried your solution and it had stalled the program instead. Nonetheless, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: stalled by resizing the vectors for their size? that's only possible if you don't have the memory to work with your data.